# How to use docker image from build step in deploy step in CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: docker, deployment, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

Struggling for a few last days to migrate from CircleCI 1.0 to 2.0 and while the build process is done, deployment is still a big issue. CircleCI documentation is not really of a big help.

Here is a similar `config.yml` to what I have:

```
version 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.9.1

    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker

      - run
          name: Install required stuff
          command: [...]

      - run:
          name: Build
          command: docker build -t project .

  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            bash scripts/deploy/deploy.sh
            docker tag project [...]
            docker push [...]

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: develop
```

The issue is in `deploy` job. I have to specify the `docker: -image` point but I want to reuse the environment from `build` job where all the required stuff is installed already. Surely, I could just install them in `deploy` job, but having multiple `deploy` jobs leads to code duplication which is something I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to persist to workspace and attach it in your deploy job.
you wont need to use '- checkout' after that

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#persist_to_workspace

```
jobs:
    build:
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:8.9.1

        steps:
            - checkout
            - setup_remote_docker

            - run
                name: Install required stuff
                command: [...]

            - run:
                  name: Build
                  command: docker build -t project .
            - persist_to_workspace:
                    root: ./
                    paths:
                        - ./

    deploy:
        docker:
            - image: circleci/node:8.9.1
        steps:
            - attach_workspace:
                at: ./
            - run:
                  name: Deploy
                  command: |
                      bash scripts/deploy/deploy.sh
                      docker tag project [...]
                      docker push [...]

workflows:
    version: 2
    build-deploy:
        jobs:
            - build
            - deploy:
                  requires:
                      - build
                  filters:
                      branches:
                          only: develop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you label the image built by the `build` stage, you can then reference it in the `deploy` stage: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#labels

Comment: Are you referring to the image `project`? If so, I guess it's not what I need in `deploy` job to have all the installed stuff. I assumed I need the same image `circleci/node:8.9.1` where I have checkouted the code and have install required stuff.